# DataFrame.corr() - Pearson linear correlation calculated with the same duplicated data?

Tags: python, pandas, pearson-correlation

`x=[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, ..., 0.3]`        (number of 0.3: 10)

```
y=x
```

What is the linear correlation coefficiency between `x` and `y`?

For this `x` and `y`, all pairs points to the same point `(0.3, 0.3)`. Can we say `x` and `y` are linear correlated?

`scipy.stats.pearsonr(x, y)` will give you Yes `(1.0, 0.0)`. But does it make sense?

However, if we change all `0.3` to `3`, scipy will give you No `(NaN, 1.0)`. Why is it different from previous (0.3) one? Related to the deviation of the floating numbers? But if we use 3.0 instead of 3, we still get No `(NaN, 1.0)`. Does any one know why different inputs generates different outputs?

```
# When using 0.3:
# result: (1.0, 0.0)
import scipy.stats
a=[]
for i in range(10):
    a.append(0.3)
b=a
scipy.stats.pearsonr(a,b)



# When using int 3:
# result: (nan, 1.0)
import scipy.stats
a=[]
for i in range(10):
    a.append(3)
b=a
scipy.stats.pearsonr(a,b)



# When using 3.0:
# result: (nan, 1.0)
import scipy.stats
a=[]
for i in range(10):
    a.append(3.0)
b=a
scipy.stats.pearsonr(a,b)
```

See the in-line comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pearson R coefficient, which assumes a normal distribution of the data, on a bunch of constants is a mathematically undefined operation.

```
xm = x - x.mean()
ym = y - y.mean()
r = sum(xm * ym) / np.sqrt( sum(xm**2) * sum(ym**2) )
```

In other words, if there is no variation in your data, you are dividing by zero.

Now the reason why it works for a repetition of the `float` 0.3:

```
a = [0.3 for _ in range(10)] #note that single-decimal only 0.3 and 0.6 fail
b = [3.0 for _ in range(10)]
print(np.asarray(a).mean(), np.asarray(b).mean())
#0.29999999999999993 3.0
print(0.3 - 0.29999999999999993)
#5.551115123125783e-17
```

So, by merit of this tiny, tiny floating point deviation stemming from the averaging operation, there is something to calculate and the correlation can be pegged at 1.0; although the application of the method is still invalid.

Comment: Many thanks - so it does related to the deviation of float. There must be some optimization so sometimes the deviation is shown and sometimes not.

Comment: It is just the floating point limitation. Try playing around with `as_integer_ratio()` (e.g. `0.1.as_integer_ratio()` ) to see what is happening with the exact representation.

Comment: Many thanks! You answered my question! However, I have too few points and I can't thumb your answer. :S

Comment: @StevenDing: True; can still accept the answer though. ;)